# DisplayMember not always being set in the CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox that I populate with a List of custom "DBitemtype" objects which I do through first setting the DataSource, then the DisplayMember, and ValueMember properties of the CheckedListBox "clbItemType". Now at runtime, the user has options to change the items so I have an event that rebinds the CheckedListBox with a different list of the same "DBitemtype" objects by first setting the DataSource to null, and then setting the DataSource to the new list, then setting the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties again to the exact same values like so:

```
clbItemType.DataSource = null;
clbItemType.DataSource = _SelectedItemTypes;  // A List<DBitemtype>
clbItemType.DisplayMember = DBitemtype.Columns.ItemName;  // String constant - value "ItemName"
clbItemType.ValueMember = DBitemtype.Columns.ID;          // String constant - value "ID"
clbItemType.Refresh();
```

Both string constants used for DisplayMember and ValueMember describe public string properties in the DBitemtype class.

The issue I'm having is that sometimes the DisplayMember gets set with "ItemName" and sometimes it doesn't and just stays as "" when I step through the code. I can't seem to find a pattern as to why it happens only sometimes. No error or exception is thrown.

Al I could find was "If the new value of the DisplayMember cannot be set, the previous value is maintained." from the msdn article here [CheckedListBox.DisplayMember Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So I guess this is a 2-part question:

1) Has anyone else had this problem?

2) What are the conditions that will cause the DisplayMember to not be set?

Comment: Ever noticed that IntelliSense wasn't very cooperative when you tried to type "DisplayMember"?  Review the MSDN article for CheckedListBox.DisplayMember and read the "Note": `You cannot bind data to a CheckedListBox`

Comment: @HansPassant Yes I noticed that IntelliSense wasn't cooperative. However, the properties do exist, and if you read the MSDN article for CheckedListBox.DisplayMember for .NET Framework version 4.0 or 3.5 (not 3.0 or previous), the note you're referring to does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I did find out that DisplayName does not like public fields (`public int x;`), only public properties (`public int x { get; set; };`).

So, I would try to make sure that `ItemName` or any other potential DisplayName values are in fact public properties of `DBitemtype`.

Answer (score 0):

It might look the same, but:

```
clbItemType.DataSource = _SelectedItemTypes;  // A List<DBitemtype>
clbItemType.DisplayMember = DBitemtype.Columns.ItemName;  // String constant - value "ItemName"
clbItemType.ValueMember = DBitemtype.Columns.ID;          // String constant - value "ID"
```

is not the same as:

```
clbItemType.DisplayMember = DBitemtype.Columns.ItemName;  // String constant - value "ItemName"
clbItemType.ValueMember = DBitemtype.Columns.ID;          // String constant - value "ID"
clbItemType.DataSource = _SelectedItemTypes;  // A List<DBitemtype>
```

Set your members first, then change your DataSource. Changing a DataSource will fire event triggers and then return to the code block.

Comment: This did not work for me, it effectively cleared out the value for DisplayMember to "" as soon as the DataSource was set in the last line of your suggestion.